# Windows 7 - Installed new SSD System Drive with strange OS issues

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, usb, ssd

I've recently installed a new SSD as the main system disk on my computer, clean formatting the previous 2 disks, but i've noticed some odd issues with how Windows is regarding the hardware.

I have 3 hard disks installed:

[image]

In the Taskbar notifications and by right-clicking my system in Devices and Printers I have the option to eject my 500GB Western Digital HHD (WDC WD50 00AAKX-001 CA0 SCSI Disk Device).  I'd rather not have the option to do this for fear that i'd have to open my case and physically reconnect the device in order for Windows to see it again.  How can remove this option?

[image]

Also, why is my `60GB SSD Drive (E:)` available from the AutoPlay option and how can i remove it?

[image]

I've also noticed that there is a `Generic Ultra HS_SD/MMC USB Device` connected but I don't understand what this is or know how I can find out.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You wouldn't have to reconnect that hard drive, rebooting would be just enough - if it would actually eject, because there's a chance that Windows won't actually let you do it. It's safe to try that out.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put too much emphasis on those menu items (esp for debugging purposes).

Verify in the BIOS that the drives show up and are connected on the ports you've connected them to.

Ensure that the Device Manager properly lists the drives.

Also go to the Disk Management control panel and verify that all the drives are listed there and have Healthy partitions (You can get there from the run dialog <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter `diskmgmt.msc`).

If the drives are working and healthy I don't think those menu items are indicative of a larger issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some motherboards allow you to set if a SATA port supports hot connect or not. Disabling hot connect for the port you are using in the BIOS settings might remove the eject options from your context menu.